# Compiler infering type arguments at call site (when computing common super-type)

Tags: scala, generics

Only `v2` compiles bellow. I'd like instead to be able to call my apply method as in the `v1` example. The compiler seems to be too quick to assign `Nothing` to my `R` variable

(inferred type arguments [...A,Nothing] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T1 <: Nothing,T2 <: Nothing]
  val v1 = apply(3)(new A)(new B))

```
class C
class A extends C
class B extends C

object O {
def apply[T1 <: R, T2 <: R, R](d : Int)(succ : T1)(fail : T2): R = if (d<0) succ else fail

  val v1 = apply(3)(new A)(new B)

  val v2 = apply[A, B, C](3)(new A)(new B)
}
```

Comment: The compiler has no easy way to infer `R`. I'm not sure why you need any type parameters at all though, because nothing is truly constrained. `R` could always be `Any`, which doesn't do much good.

Comment: Because later I can do structural recursion on `R` (So `R` is supposed to be a sum type)

Answer (score 0):

As presented, I'd just simplify the signature to `def apply[R](d: Int, succ: R, fail: R): R`. It has legal type parameters iff your original signature does, but the compiler can infer the single remaining type parameter much better.

Comment: You are correct, I made things too complicated as i don't really need T1 & T2 type params. However, removing them also doesn't help (your example shows that) as the resulting type is still not computed automatically by the compiler

Comment: The example was intended for your original signature (as you can see from 3 parameter lists). After double-checking it didn't actually work but unfortunately I forgot to delete it. For the modified signature result type should be inferred.

Comment: Yup, my initial question is actually unremarkable. The difficulty lied solely in my use of multiple argument lists. So understanding how type inferrence works in conjuction with multiple is the interesting bit

Comment: @CristianMartin Taking http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#local-type-inference literally, only the first parameter list should be used for type parameter inference. Given that your answer works, it looks like actually the first parameter list which uses any type parameters. (An important reason parameter lists influence type inference at all is so that functions in later parameter lists can have already known input types.)

Comment: No, that's not quite right : `only the first parameter list should be used for type parameter inference`. In my answe I used the second list for inferrence and it worked fine. While I do appreciate your effort of digging a bit of specs, I must admit there's little I understand of it. I should check them more often !

Comment: @CristianMartin Did you miss the next sentence?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've found a solution for my question. I figured collections do something similar when adding two of different types. So this is something that infers its result automatically :

```
def apply[S, R >: S](d : Int)(succ : S, fail : R): R = if ( d < 0 ) succ else fail
```

Oddly only works when succ & fail belong to the same parameter list. I wonder why is that